# How do I drill through steel?

Tags: drill

I was trying to drill through my stucco wall and hit a very hard surface that the drill would not go through.  I then purchased a titanium drill bit that I was told would drill through steel, which I think is what is behind the stucco.  However, I can't get the drill to make a hole.  How long does it take to drill through steel and am I using the correct drill bit?

Comment: are you sure it's not concrete?

Comment: Or a conduit or plate protecting wires from being nailed into - or a pipe? There are many possibilities here, and some of them are not good to drill into, so it helps to be fairly sure before you start turning up the drill technology.

Comment: Do you have wooden or steel framing studs?

Answer (score 7):

Ecnerwal raises a good point - I would want to know for sure what it is before drilling through it.  Metal plates are often put in around wires and pipes specifically to stop you from accidentally drilling into them - you could break electrical wires or plumbing, potentially causing a fire or a flood.

The plates work like this image shows:
[image: Nail Protection Plate]

The best thing to do here probably isnt applying more force - either drill somewhere else, or open up a small hole in the wall around it so you can see what you are breaking, then decide if its still a good idea.

As for what will drill through it - it depends on exactly what it is and how thick it is.  Drilling through strong thick steel requires lubricating oil so you dont overheat and damage the drill bits.  They will dull very fast without it.

Comment: That may very well be the problem.  I'm going to change the placement of the rack I am trying to hang and hopefully find a safe place to drill.  Thanks for the help.  I never realized that there were steel plates placed behind the wall to safeguard wires and pipes.